# One chinese character won´t appear in pdf

Tags: xecjk, rendering, chinese

I am typesetting a german-english text with some chinese characters in it. I know similar questions have been asked often here, but none of the answers provided any help. I tried the following:

```
    % Version 1: 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
\begin{document}
waijiaquan, 外家拳
neijiaquan, 內家拳
\end{document}
```

```
  %Version 2
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures[FandolSong]{Script=Default}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
\begin{document}
waijiaquan, 外家拳
neijiaquan, 內家拳
\end{document}
```

```
  % Version 3
\documentclass[fontset=windows]{ctexbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures[FandolSong]{Script=Default}
\begin{document}
waijiaquan, 外家拳
neijiaquan, 內家拳
\end{document}
```

```
% Version 4
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\AtBeginDvi{\input{zhwinfonts}}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{zhsong}
    waijiaquan, 外家拳
    neijiaquan, 內家拳
    \end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

I always get warnings that a font is missing, Fandol or SimHei. BUT: I read on CTAN they are included in TexLive and Miktex, which I use both. So what´s the fundamental mistake here, and which options are left?

Comment: I have fandol in miktex and texlive, but the font doesn't have one of your characters: `Missing character: There is no 內 in font [FandolSong-Regular.otf]`

Comment: Thanks.How do I install a single character in one font in Texlive or Miktex? This my provide help for the SimHei Problem as well. In my other examples I got a >missingfont< logfile , so I installed the missing font SimHei. It didn´t help.

Comment: you can't add a char,  you need a font which has it. I don't have simhei, it seem to have been included in windows 8.1 but not in windows 10. With simsun all your chars appear.

Comment: Babelstone Han has a particularly-comprehensive set of Chinese characters.

Comment: I tried babelstone HAN; the font wasn´t found. I tried SimHei after installing it in my system, , it wasnt found. Same for SimSun. Even Noto etc. gives me the warning:

Comment: I tried babelstone HAN; the font wasn´t found. I tried SimHei after installing it in my system, , it wasnt found. Same for SimSun. Even Noto etc. gives me the warning:I tried babelstone HAN; the font wasn´t found. I tried SimHei AFTER installing it in my system, it wasnt found. Same for SimSun. Even Noto Sans CJK cannot be found, and also  the warning > invalid filename<, and >unknown slotnumber (microtype). <  appear. There seems to be more wrong than just a missing character.

Comment: The examples work fine with the changes, but the main text doesn´t render properly.

Comment: Well.. thanks, it worked. Merely the whole text is in SimSun now. I need some characters in chinese, the rest of the text is in Palatino and must remain, for I am compiling an Anthology. So, how do I get some characters - those in the example - in chinese in a german-english text otherwise in Palation?

Answer (score 3):

Your font is missing that character.  You can add the command `\tracinglostchars=2` to print a warning message on the console, instead of silently printing it to the `.log` file.

For this kind of multilingual document, with only short phrases in Chinese, I would recommend Babel.  This MWE works on LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2 % Warn if a character is missing from the font!
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelprovide[import=zh-Hans, onchar=ids fonts]{chinese} % Or zh-Hant for Traditional.
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0, Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}]{New Computer Modern Book}
% From: https://www.google.com/get/noto/#serif-hans or https://www.ctan.org/pkg/notocjksc
\babelfont[chinese]{rm}
          {Noto Serif CJK SC}
% Set up \babelfont{sf} and \babelfont{tt} here, if needed.

\babeltags{chinese=chinese}
\babeltags{english=english}
\babeltags{ngerman=german}

\begin{document}
waijiaquan, 外家拳
neijiaquan, 內家拳
\end{document}
```

This will get you German captions and hyphenation, but automatically switch when you start typing Chinese.  It also lets you switch languages with `\textenglish{...}`, `\begin{english}`, and so on.

To get the document to compile on XeLaTeX, remove the `onchar=ids fonts` option and wrap all Chinese text in `\textchinese{外家拳}`. This is also compatible with `polyglossia`.

The `ctex` package, which is more recent than XeCJK and also works on other engines, provides two ways to select a different font: `fontset=` and `\setCJKmainfont` (also `\setCJKsansfont` and `\setCJKmonofont`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2 % Warn if a character is missing from the font!
\usepackage[UTF8, fontset=none]{ctex}

% From: https://www.google.com/get/noto/#serif-hans or https://www.ctan.org/pkg/notocjksc
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Noto Serif CJK SC}

\begin{document}
waijiaquan, 外家拳
neijiaquan, 內家拳
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this works without any problems. I had to change Noto to SimSun, for Noto etc. wasn´t found either. Now merely >babelfont< and >defaultfontfeatures< is marked in red, so I think there is still something wrong. But the rendering is flawless. wasn´t found as well.

Comment: @Andrea Oh, sorry. The Noto Serif CJK SC font is available [on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/notocjksc) or [from Google.](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#serif-hans)

Comment: @Andrea Added links to the font download. Or you can use your fonts of choice; that was just an example.

Comment: @Andrea I’m not sure what you mean by “marked in red,” but that sounds like your editor’s syntax highlighting perhaps doesn’t recognize them? They’re somewhat newer commands.

Comment: i am working with TexLive and Miktex, the latest version. Yes. I meant that highlighting. And theres another thing I had to set right. The  \babeltags had to be deleted all, or my PDF-Viewer (Adobe Acrobat Reader) wouldn´t find  a particular embedded font. But now its working.

Comment: @Andrea That’s a bit confusing, since TeX Live and MikTeX are two different TeX distributions, and neither is a text editor, which is what would be doing syntax highlighting. I also don’t know why `\babeltags` would cause that problem. But I’m glad it worked.

Comment: I know it is. So it was to me. My  editor  is TexStudio. But I don´t know which distribution it uses by default. The one with the more recent version? The one that was installed first? But that ´s too far off topic.

Answer (score 2):

With SimSun (which I got with Windows 10) your chars are all there too

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{SimSun}
\begin{document}
waijiaquan, 外家拳
neijiaquan, 內家拳
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can download Google's [Noto Serif CJK and Noto Sans CJK font families](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/), you may want to try the following version, labelled "version 5", which runs under both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. The Noto Serif CJK TC font family provides 6 font weights (from "Extra Light" to "Black"), and the Noto Sans CJK TC font family provides 7 font weights (from "Thin" to "Black").

[image]

```
 % Version 5
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif CJK TC} 
\setsansfont{Noto Sans CJK TC}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}
    Hello World. 
    waijiaquan, 外家拳.
    neijiaquan, 內家拳.
    
\sffamily
    Hello World. 
    waijiaquan, 外家拳.
    neijiaquan, 內家拳.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did download SimHei, installeed it to Windows 10, and yet latex couldn´t find it. So I keep with what works until now and keep this in my HELP-Storage. If I am not obliged to stick to a peculiar font.

Comment: @Andrea - Real quick: did you intend to post this comment below [Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567747/5001)?

Comment: Sorry if it´s in the wrong place. I only recently understood  that you can comment any answer by itself, not all together at the queue´s bottom.

Comment: @Andrea - The reason I posted a comment a couple of days ago is that my answer doesn't mention either the SimHei font or Windows 10. I'm a Mac person through and through, and I'm not ashamed to admit that I know next to nothing about how to get anything done under Windows. I still think that your initial comment might elicit a more directed response if it were posted below Ulrike's answer.

Comment: Possibly, but it works now, with the forum´s help. I´m totally content with the result.